# SwiftUI Mac menu command to create a single instance of a window?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, menu

I found that if I define a Window struct in my SwiftUI applications App struct, it creates a window that I can then open from a menu command with an environment variable.

However, the system opens the window at launch. What I want is a singe-instance of an info window that is ideally created lazily from a menu command, destroyed on close, and recreated the next time it the menu command is invoked. (I'm going to use it to display log information about the processing the app does.)

Failing that, I'd like the window to be created hidden, and then un-hidden with a menu command.

How would I do that? If I add .hidden to the window, it is hidden forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood something you can use `Window` to have a window that you open separately, add it to the `body` in main but outside the any `WindowGroup`

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
    }

    Window("Info Window",id: "info-window") {
        InfoWindowView()
    }
    .keyboardShortcut(KeyEquivalent("i"), modifiers: [.command, .shift])
}
```

This window can then be opened from the Window menu, Window -> Info Window or with the keyboard shortcut Cmd-Shift-I

Comment: Ok, that seems to work as well. At first I thought it opened the window every time, but it just reopens it if you had it open before. This seems like the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

If your app has a `MenuBarExtra`, move it to the very start of `var body: some Scene { ... }`. If the `MenuBarExtra` is the first `Scene`, the `Window`/`WindowGroup` scene will not appear on launch.

```
@main
struct FooApp: App {
    @Environment(\.openWindow) var open
    var body: some Scene {
        MenuBarExtra("Extra Menu") {
            // ...
        }
        
        WindowGroup(id: "ID") {
            ContentView()
        }
        .commands {
            CommandMenu("Foo") {
                Button("Open Window") {
                    open(id: "ID")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want/need a `MenuBarExtra`, you can do:

```
MenuBarExtra("") { }
```

which makes it practically invisible.

That said, if I launch an app, I would expect to see a window popping up, or a new menu bar extra in the menu bar. Launching an app and then nothing happens except the app name on the top left changing is a bit weird.

Comment: The app does open a window. This is an optional info window that I don't want to open by default. Thank you for the solution of having an empty MenuBarExtra. That does indeed make my window not open by default. (Voted.) That's an obscure solution that seems more like a side-effect than a clear way to express what I want though.

Comment: @DuncanC if you want a “clear” way, just wrap the menu bar extra into your own `Scene`. Then you can give it as clear a name as you like. e.g. `NoInitialWindow`.

Comment: See Joakim's answer. I just moved the Menu definition to the end of my Scene, outside of my WindowGroups, and that works too.

Comment: @DuncanC Oh, it seems like I misunderstood the question then. I thought you didn't want *any* window to show up on launch. It is *trivial* if you just want one particular window to not show up initially, as Joakim's answer shows, and I thought you couldn't possibly be asking about that.

Comment: @DuncanC That makes me wonder, what did you even try, if not adding another `Window` to `body`? Did you put it as the first scene or something?

Comment: It might be trivial but I had no idea how to do it. I don't remember how I had the code initially. I'm still looking for a good reference to teach me SwiftUI. I feel like I'm fumbling around in the dark.

Comment: @DuncanC I see. The [Apple Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/SwiftUI) is a good starting point. While it focuses on iOS, most of the techniques you will learn from there, also applies to macOS.